# How are we suppose to set a ManyToMany relationship in Apollo GraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo

I want to have a ManyToMany relation between `Notification` and `User` (Recipients).

So from what I [understood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892343/how-to-set-many-to-many-relation-in-graphql-mutation) you have to create an intermediary Type Which will be something like NotificationRecipients.

However what kind of relation shall I do ?

Is it something like

```
Notification OneToMany <---> ManyToOne NotificationRecipients ManyToOne <---> OneToMany User
```

This is not explain anywhere in the documentation of apollo. And this does not sounds good since it should be ManyToMany relation everywhere...

Is there a `@ManyToMany` directive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Relation" isn't really a first-class term in GraphQL.  If Notification has many Users, you'd just say that, and vice versa

```graphql
type Notification {
  users: [User!]!
}
type User {
  notifications: [Notification!]!
}
```

As the answer to the linked question notes, you can use the Relay connection pattern here if it's appropriate to you.

Actually implementing this is up to you (in your resolver function), or the database glue layer you're using.  GraphQL just defines an API here and it's not rigidly tied to your database layout.